# How can I move a file and append a timestamp to its name via cron job?

Tags: cron, cron-task, crontrigger

I have a file `CBD_DATA.zip` present in a directory: `/home/cbd_dev/CBD_DATA.zip`. I want to move it to the directory `/home/sundaram_srivastava/archives/` as `CBD_DATA_{DateTimeStamp}.zip`.

I have tried using a cron job:

```sh
* * * * * mv /home/cbd_dev/CBD_DATA.zip /home/sundaram_srivastava/archives > /home/sundaram_srivastava/archives/CBD_DATA_`date +\%d\%m\%y`.zip
```

The problem with the cron job above is that it moves the file as `CBD_DATA.zip` into another directory with the same name and then it creates another file  `CBD_DATA_110620`.

Now, the file `CBD_DATA_110620` is 0 KB. So, in the destination directory, I have two files, `CBD_DATA.zip` and `CBD_DATA_110620`, but I want just one and it should not be empty.

What should I change in my cron code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd try and figure out the command on its own, without a cron job. What you're doing is something like this (with shortened directory paths for readability):

```sh
mv /foo/CBD_DATA.zip /foo/archives > /foo/archives/CBD_DATA_`date +%d%m%y`.zip
```

This moves the file and then creates a new empty file; there is no output from the `mv` command, and the redirection has nothing to redirect, so the file with the datestamp is empty.

The second argument for the `mv` command is the new location itself; if it is a directory, the filename stays the same, but if it is not a directory, it is interpreted as the new name. You don't need any redirection.

```sh
mv /foo/CBD_DATA.zip "/foo/archives/CBD_DATA_$(date '+%d%m%y').zip"
```

I have replaced the deprecated backticks in the command substitution with `$(...)` and quoted the expansion. Side note: if you can choose the datestamp format, I'd strongly recommend using `+%F` (or `%Y%m%d`) instead so it sorts chronologically.

With your paths and escaped for a cron job (do you really want to run this every minute?):

```sh
* * * * * mv /home/cbd_dev/CBD_DATA.zip "/home/sundaram_srivastava/archives/CBD_DATA_$(date +\%d\%m\%y).zip"
```

Comment: I'm running this every minute for my unit testing. It will not be like that in actual job.

Comment: Thanxx for your answer & it is very well explained..really appreciate it...!!!